# How to add a xml file header with vb.net

Tags: xml, vb.net

I want to add xml declaration like

**?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?**

this text in my xml. How to do it with vb.net ? any idea?

Comment: Why do you need to add a header? Would it not be easier to create a document, then add nodes to it? In this case, it will already have the header in place.

Comment: @Neolisk its not adding the header automatically. for my stuff I need to add it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Dim xmlDoc As New XmlDocument()
xmlDoc.AppendChild(.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", Nothing))
```

Refer to MSDN for more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.createxmldeclaration.aspx

Comment: Dim xmldecl As XmlDeclaration

        xmldecl = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", Nothing, Nothing)
        xmldecl.Encoding = "UTF-8"
        xmldecl.Standalone = "yes"

        doc.AppendChild(xmldecl)

Comment: I tried this. and it worked. but I followed your suggestion. thanks anyway.

Comment: <?eclipse-pydev version="1.0"?>

now I want to add this header. Any idea??

Comment: @istiaq2379 -- I'd suggest following the documentation at the link I sent.  Or ask as a separate question.  If I've answered this question for you, please accept it as the answer.